# Are there any disadvantage in dispatch a bubbling CustomEvent?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

The second parameter of `Event` constructor is the `eventInit` dictionary.

By default, the key `bubbles` in `eventInit` is set to `false`.

My question is: when creating a custom event, are there some disadvantages in setting it to `true`? In other words, should I set it to `true` just if there is a strong reason?

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

Comment: When setting `bubbles` property to `true`, you can fire the same event on the ancestor elements (if attached), when set to `false`, the event doesn't bubble, and it is fired only on the element it is attached to. You can play with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skhtg20x/), open the console, run the code, and change the bubble value, run again. You'll see what is done differently.

Comment: @Teemu, I do understand the differences. My question is: since the default value is `false`, are there any _disadvantages_ in setting it to `true`?

Comment: There's no pros or cons on the bubble value, the event just behaves differently depending on that value. If you need bubbling, then you set it to `true`, if you don't, then leave it `false`. If there's a perfomance loss when letting an event to bubble, it's negligible, most of the DOM events are bubbling anyway.